# EAP-PWD with FreeRADIUS 3

Tags: wifi, radius, freeradius, wpa, eap

I'm trying to setup EAP-PWD using FreeRADIUS 3.

However, I can't get it to work and documentation is virtually non-existent. Thus, I don't know whether the problem I'm running into is a misconfiguration or an actual bug.

## Configuration

This is my configuration (at least the parts that are relevant):

mods-enabled/eap:

```
eap {
    pwd {
    #group = 19

    server_id = example@example.com

    #  This has the same meaning as for TLS.
    fragment_size = 1020

    # The virtual server which determines the "known good" password for the user.
    # Note that unlike TLS, only the "authorize" section is processed.
    # EAP-PWD requests can be distinguished by having a User-Name, but no User-Password, CHAP-Password, EAP-Message, etc.
    #virtual_server = "inner-tunnel"
}
```

I don't know what `group = 19` is supposed to mean. (It's explained nowhere)

sites-enabled/default:

```
authorize {
    filter_username
    preprocess

    #  Look in an SQL database.
    sql

    #permit_only_eap
    eap {
        ok = return
    }

    logintime
}

authenticate {
    #  Allow EAP authentication.
    eap
}
```

sites-enabled/inner-tunnel:

```
authorize {
    eap {
        ok = return
    }

    #  Look in an SQL database.
    sql

    expiration
}

authenticate {
    mschap

    #  Allow EAP authentication.
    eap
}
```

Honestly, I don't understand if/why EAP-PWD needs a tunneled request anyway. I had it setup because I use PEAPv0/MS-CHAPv2 as well. I tried both virtual servers (default and inner-tunnel)

## Problem

Well, the problem. I get authentication errors on the supplicant. This is what I see in the logs:

```
(2) eap: Peer sent method PWD (52)
(2) eap: EAP PWD (52)
(2) eap: Calling eap_pwd to process EAP data
(2) eap_pwd: Sending tunneled request
(2) eap_pwd: server default {
(2) # Executing section authorize from file /etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/default
(2)   authorize {
(2)     policy filter_username {
(2)       if (!&User-Name) {
(2)       if (!&User-Name)  -> TRUE
(2)       if (!&User-Name)  {
(2)         [noop] = noop
(2)       } # if (!&User-Name)  = noop
(2)       if (&User-Name =~ / /) {
(2)       ERROR: Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition
(2)       if (&User-Name =~ /@.*@/ ) {
(2)       ERROR: Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition
(2)       if (&User-Name =~ /\.\./ ) {
(2)       ERROR: Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition
(2)       if ((&User-Name =~ /@/) && (&User-Name !~ /@(.+)\.(.+)$/))  {
(2)       ERROR: Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition
(2)       if (&User-Name =~ /\.$/)  {
(2)       ERROR: Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition
(2)       if (&User-Name =~ /@\./)  {
(2)       ERROR: Failed retrieving values required to evaluate condition
(2)     } # policy filter_username = noop
(2)     [preprocess] = ok
(2) sql: EXPAND %{User-Name}
(2) sql:    -->
(2) sql: SQL-User-Name set to ''
rlm_sql (sql): Reserved connection (4)
(2) sql: EXPAND SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY id
(2) sql:    --> SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '' ORDER BY id
(2) sql: Executing select query: SELECT id, username, attribute, value, op FROM radcheck WHERE username = '' ORDER BY id
(2) sql: EXPAND SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = '%{SQL-User-Name}' ORDER BY priority
(2) sql:    --> SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = '' ORDER BY priority
(2) sql: Executing select query: SELECT groupname FROM radusergroup WHERE username = '' ORDER BY priority
(2) sql: User not found in any groups
rlm_sql (sql): Released connection (4)
(2)     [sql] = notfound
(2) eap: No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
(2)     [eap] = noop
(2)     [logintime] = noop
(2)   } # authorize = ok
(2) eap_pwd: } # server default
(2) eap_pwd: Got tunneled reply code 0
failed to find password for lars to do pwd authentication
(2) eap: ERROR: Failed continuing EAP PWD (52) session. EAP sub-module failed
(2) eap: Failed in EAP select
(2)     [eap] = invalid
(2)   } # authenticate = invalid
(2) Failed to authenticate the user
(2) Login incorrect (eap: Failed continuing EAP PWD (52) session. EAP sub-module failed): [lars] (from client LARS-RANNOCH port 4 cli 48-59-29-F6-BA-89)
```

The first authorize section (not shown in above log) went OK, but after that EAP-PWD seems to do another tunneled request. (why? I thought that was only necessary for PEAP and EAP-TTLS). In this case I had outcommented the "virtual-server"-line in the EAP config, so the request was handled by the default virtual server.

As can be seen, the *User-Name* attribute is empty (`SQL-User-Name set to ''`), which results in the sql module not being able to fetch the correct record: `failed to find password for lars to do pwd authentication`.

Is my configuration for EAP-PWD correct? What causes this error?

Comment: The reason for the tunnelling appears to be because the the peer is expected to provide an ID, which may differ from the EAP-Identity-Response sent to the NAS. So the issue here is you're not getting the Peer-Identity written to the User-Name attribute. Could  you provide your wpa_supplicant/eapol_test config for testing.

Comment: Right, thanks for clearing that up!

Actually I was testing using my phone (Nexus 5 running CM11)

Comment: So it could be a supplicant issue as well. Hmm. .pcap would help. Could you DM me on twitter, then i'll give you another contact address. I think this'll need some interactive debugging. EAP-PWD support is fairly new and not well tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug. The person who developed the original PWD code only added the User-Name VALUE_PAIR to the request's user-name caching pointer, not to the actual request list.

Some modules ignore the pointer, it was crappy optimisation from a long time ago.

Adding the pair to the request list fixes the issue. Here's the [commit](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/commit/ef049769d78623a04e78ab1ec7317d1f73bee098).

Thanks for helping track down this issue. The fix will be released as part of v3.0.8. In the mean time you can download [v3.0.x HEAD](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/archive/v3.1.x.zip) and try that.

After setting `control:Cleartext-Password` in the inner tunnel, I got sever successful authentications. Hopefully it'll work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Your link links to freeradius-3.1.x (not 3.0.x), is that intentional?

Comment: I just downloaded v3.0.x HEAD (since I saw you committed the fix to both branches) and I think I got it working! At least the eapol_test now succeeds. I will test it later this day with my Android phone.

Comment: Great! and the commit is the same across both branches and people should cherry-pick across.